# Run macro when linked cell changes value (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am currently trying to obtain historical information about how the backlog is developing.

My Excel file is based on queries from an Access Database which can give me a view of the current situation.

I would like to automatically run a macro every time the week number changes. I am currently using the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D3")) Is Nothing Then
        Call KPIupdate
    End If
End Sub
```

The macro that should fire is called KPIupdate

My problem is that the Macro only fires if I click the cell. I would like it to just fire when the number changes. The cell "D3" is linked to another cell with the formula =Weeknum(Today();21)

I hope you can help me

Comment: You need to use the `Calculate()` Event rather than the `Change()` Event.

Comment: Hi Gary, I am new at VBA. Can you give me an example of what the code will look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) entry for `Worksheet_Change`:

> This event does not occur when cells change during a recalculation. Use the Calculate event to trap a sheet recalculation.

To use `Worksheet_Calculate` to trap the change in a cell that is set by a formula looking at another cell, you need to set a variable to hold the value of the 'Target' and then check if it has changed after the `Calculate` event fires.

Here is a simple example:

```
Option Explicit

Private strCurrentWeek As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Me.Range("A1").Value <> strCurrentWeek Then
        'the linked cell changed
        Debug.Print "Sheet1!A1 was changed"
        'call another macro
    End If
    'update the new current week
    strCurrentWeek = Me.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

To test this, just set the formula in `A1` to be `=B1` and then change the value of `B1` and check the output in the Immediate window.

You can adapt this code to call `KPIupdate` where my `Debug.Print...` statement is.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and helping me :-) There is still a problem. Every time any cell is changed it is running the macro. Can the problem be related to that the cell is linked to a cell with the formula  (=Today)? I am thinking that maybe excel thinks the number is updated because it keeps looking for the day? 

If I make a test excel sheet it keeps running the macro if I refer to a cell with the Today formula.

Do you know how to get rid of that problem?

Comment: Yes - the macro will run anytime the worksheet is calculated. However, the logic in the code means that nothing will happen unless the value in A1 changes. I tested with B1 containing `=TODAY()` and A1 containing `=B1` and the code within the IF block doesn't run. However if B1 contains `=NOW()` then the inner logic fires every recalculation (as the time has moved on).

Comment: Thank you. It is almost working perfectly now. Maybe you can help me with a last question. 
Every time I open the file it is running the macro because it is not remembering the strCurrentWeek = Me.Range("A1").Value. Can this be solved somehow?

Comment: It's a broad question There are a number of ways to save 'application settings' across sessions of Excel. You could use a special sheet within the workbook, .ini or .cfg files, the registry, etc etc. Perhaps you should start another question for this?